# Fragment Edittext not editable, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm having a problem with my edittext inside a `Fragment`. the text inside the edittext cannot be edited. though the cursor is shown and the initial value of text is shown (as well as the hint), I cannot edit the text anymore. Is there a problem in edittext inside Fragment. This is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings,
            container, false);

    LinearLayout settingscontent = (LinearLayout) vg
            .findViewById(R.id.settingscontent);


    final EditText displayname_et = new EditText(getActivity());
    displayname_et.setId(R.id.displayname_et);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p_ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 0.5f);
    displayname_et.setLayoutParams(p_ll);
    displayname_et.setSingleLine();
    int textsize = WindowSize.convertedSize(20); //just a modified integer from my custom class
    displayname_et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);
    displayname_et.setTextScaleX(WindowSize.getTextScaleX()); //just a modified float from my custom class
    displayname_et.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    displayname_et.setHint("Display Name");
    displayname_et.setText("migs");
    displayname_et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    settingscontent.addView(displayname_et);
}
```

my xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settingscontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what do you do with displayname_et later on?

Comment: @itziksamara there is no seteditable(true); // pskink actually the fragment is inside a FragmentTabHost. Is there an issue with FragmentTabHost? I need a tab where I can have an edittext. can you please send me example if it can be done?

Comment: you didnt answer how you add `displayname_et` to the view hierarchy

Comment: why dont you add your EditText in xml file?

Comment: there's too many dynamic views in the fragment. I just did not include it in the question. But in my other activities. the edittext is working. only inside the fragment it is not working

Comment: I've tried adding one edittext in fragment using xml, but no luck :(